# Seeking Solution for NullPointerException in Flutter Camera App with TFLite Integration

Tags: flutter, camera, crash, tflite

I'm currently working on a Flutter camera application that incorporates the camera and tflite packages. Regrettably, I've encountered a persistent NullPointerException that appears to be closely linked to the TflitePlugin.GetTopN method, as evidenced by the error log below. I'm reaching out to the community to help me uncover any potential correlations between the tflite and camera modules that might be triggering this issue.

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15272): Process: com.example.cashvisionv2, PID: 15272
E/AndroidRuntime(15272): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Vector.size()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.GetTopN(TflitePlugin.java:282)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.access$200(TflitePlugin.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnFrame.onRunTfliteDone(TflitePlugin.java:570)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.onPostExecute(TflitePlugin.java:477)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.onPostExecute(TflitePlugin.java:445)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8105)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(15272):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

My home.dart:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import './main.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  CameraImage? cameraImage;
  CameraController? cameraController;
  String output = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadCamera();
    loadmodel();
  }

  loadCamera() {
    cameraController = CameraController(
      cameras![0],
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
    );
    cameraController!.initialize().then((value) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      } else {
        setState(() {
          cameraController!.startImageStream((imageStream) {
            cameraImage = imageStream;
            runModel();
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  runModel() async {
    if (cameraImage != null) {
      var predictions = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
        bytesList: cameraImage!.planes.map(
          (plane) {
            return plane.bytes;
          },
        ).toList(),
        imageHeight: cameraImage!.height,
        imageWidth: cameraImage!.width,
        imageMean: 127.5,
        imageStd: 127.5,
        rotation: 90,
        numResults: 2,
        threshold: 0.6,
        asynch: true,
      );
      predictions!.forEach((element) {
        setState(() {
          output = element['label'];
        });
      });
    }
  }

  loadmodel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/model.tflite",
      labels: "assets/labels.txt",
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'CashVisionV2',
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: !cameraController!.value.isInitialized
                ? Container()
                : AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: cameraController!.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: CameraPreview(cameraController!),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          output,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I have carefully reviewed my code and configuration, ensuring proper initialization and utilization of both the camera and tflite packages. I've also cross-referenced my implementation with relevant documentation and examples, but the issue persists.